# What are good reasons to use static methods in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, static-methods

Does anyone have any good examples of using static methods instead of dynamic?

Answer (score 8):

### Singleton:

```
class SingletonClass {
    private static $instance;
    private function __construct() { }
    public function __clone() {
        trigger_error('Clone is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    public static function init() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $c = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $c;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    // other public, dynamic methods for singleton
}

$singleton = SingletonClass::init();
```

### Track number of instances:

```
class CountMe {
    public static $instances = 0;
    public function __construct() {
        CountMe::$instances++;
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        CountMe::$instances--;
    }
}
$a = new CountMe();
$b = new CountMe();
echo CountMe::$instances; // outputs 2
```

Comment: Something missing. Why did you used init() instead of __construct? Why should i call init() instead of just using the method i need and let the class create its instance in the __construct?

Comment: Because the constructor is private.  This ensures that you can't create the class yourself.  You have to go through the init method, and the init method either returns a single instance, or creates one and returns it.  In this way, you will always only have a single instance of the class.

Comment: The whole purpose of a singleton is to be just that: single. This structure prevents multiple instances of an object from being created.

Comment: In other words:  You cannot do this `$var = new SingletonClass();` because an error will be thrown.  But the static method can do this `self::$instance = new $c;` because it has access to the private constructor.

Comment: Lastly, if you were given access to `__construct`, you would have to instantiate the class every time you want to get an instance of it, thus:  not a singleton.

Answer (score 4):

When you don't need access to instance members.

Answer (score 2):

A database connection would be a good use for a static function.  You dont need direct access to an entire DB object, you just need access to the connection resource.  So you can call

```
 $connection = new DatabaseConnection();
 StaticClass::setDatabase($connection);
 $result = StaticClass::getDatabaseConnection()->query();
```

But if you need access to the class for storage later or multiple instances of the same object, then you would not want to go static.

Your class also now lives in a global scope, so you can access it from any class, in any scope, anywhere in your codebase.

```
function getUsers()
{
     $users = StaticClass::getDatabaseConnection()->query('SELECT * FROM users');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a less code-oriented nature, here's how I define static methods (I'll use a bank as an example):
If you had a bank class and would like to open a new bank you would use:

```
$b = new Bank;
```

Now let's say you wanted to add a new employee to this bank. Simply call:

```
$b->addEmployee( 'Person' );
```

Since you are applying the action to the bank you created and not the company that owns the bank as a whole you use a member method. Now let's say the company's traded some assets and made money. To update their total money you would call this:

```
Bank::addToCompanyBalance( 1000000 );
```

Notice how since the action wasn't just being applied to the bank we created, we used a static method instead.

Granted this example is very oversimplified, but I like the analogy. In a more programmatic  sense case, static members are good for:

**Singletons**

```
class Singleton
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {}
    private function __clone() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if( !isset( self::$instance ) ) self::$instance = new IamOne;
        return( self::$instance );
    }
}
```

**Creating classes that may fail**
Ex. A file handler class may not always want to create a new object (Say the file passed doesn't exist or can't be opened).

**With abstract classes**
Some classes may not wish to have instances (Ex. A router that interprets a user's request). Abstract classes, however, can be called statically and therefore can use static methods.

Comment: That helped me out a lot. Sometimes it really helps to use a real-world example, like your bank, instead of showing over-technical use-cases that might not make any sense to someone unfamiliar with the concept (\*cough\* most PHP.net documentation). I've just started learning to use classes to make plugins and wanted to know why people use static vs. non-static methods and properties.

Answer (score 0):

Example:   Use static methods to create instances of an object which might perhaps take different arguments.

```
Class DBConnection
{
    public static function createFromConfiguration(Configuration $config)
    {
        $conn = new DBConnection();
        $conn->setDsn($config->getDBDsn());
        $conn->setUser($config->getDBUser());
        $conn->setPassword($config->getDBPass());

        return $conn;
    }

    public static function newConnection($dsn, $user, $password)
    {
        $conn = new DBConnection();
        $conn->setDsn($dsn);
        $conn->setUser($user);
        $conn->setPassword($password);

        return $conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dunno if I like this implementation.  Strategy Pattern would be better, I think.

Comment: Strategy pattern encapsulates objects, this is a factory system for creating objects.   It's a workaround for no support for method, in this case constructor, overloading in PHP.

Comment: There's a better way to fake method overloading.  PHP has some cool magic methods like `__call` to help.  Check this out:  http://www.dinke.net/blog/en/2007/08/01/method-overloading-in-php5/

Comment: Where do you find out about these patterns and their names?

Comment: @Kyle Wikipedia is a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns and if you want more then look at some of the classic books: http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612