# PHP static methods vs non-static methods/standard functions

Tags: php, oop

I am working on a web app and writing pure OOP based PHP for the first time. And I have a question about static method VS standard function:

Here is an example scenario:

```
class Session
{
    public function start_new_session()
    {
        session_start();
        //other code here like token generator
    }
}
```

**VS**

```
class Session
{
    static function start_new_session()
    {
        session_start();
        //other code here like token generator
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. What is the difference in both?
2. Which is better for my case?
3. Any application? (I mean, what are the best scenario to use static method and standard function)

**My Research:**

I spent some time to find the answer but don't found relevant answer however I found a lot of debate and useful material. Believe me it is super hard to decide (Who is right/wrong?) for a beginner like me:

1. [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690478/functions-vs-static-methods) Someone said, **It's horrible idea to use cookies in static functions** and someone's saying **It's a great idea**
2. And [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472721/performance-of-static-methods-vs-functions): Everyone is debating on performance and some experts are saying, the static functions execute faster and some saying; functions are faster. And result also vary because of different versions of php.

**Some useful stat:**

**PHP 5.2** : static methods are ~10-15% faster.

**PHP 5.3** : non-static methods are ~15% faster

**PHP 5.4** : static methods are ~10-15% faster

**PHP 5.5** : static methods are ~20% faster

Comment: Faster? Based on what benchmarks? And how do adjust for existence of tight coupling?

Comment: Based on this [Benchmark](http://www.codedwell.com/post/59/static-vs-non-static-methods-in-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To call a non-static method you need to instantiate the class (use the `new` keyword to create a new instance of the class).

When calling a static method you don't have to "new it up" but it won't have direct access to any of the non-static properties or methods. There are dozens of use-cases / scenarios where you might want to use one over the other.

To be quite honest it has never even crossed my mind to think about *performance* of using one over the other. If it got to a point where it made that much of a noticeable difference (and all major steps had been taken to increase efficiency) then I would imagine that either the maintenance costs of such a big application would outweigh the need for the increased efficiency or the logic behind the app is fairly flawed to begin with.

---

**Examples for static and non-static**

If I was going to use a class for the example in your question then I would use the static version as nothing in the method is reliant on other properties of the class and you then don't have to instantiate it:

```
Session::start_new_session()
```

vs

```
$session = new Session();

$session->start_new_session();
```

Also, static properties on a class will remember state that would have otherwise been lost if you were to use a non-static property and instantiation:

```
class Session
{
    protected static $sessionStarted = false;

    static function start_new_session()
    {
        if (!static::$sessionStarted) {
            session_start();
            static::$sessionStarted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then even if you did:

```
$session = new Session();

$hasStated = $session::sessionStarted;
```

`$hasStarted` would still be `true`.

You could even do something like:

```
class Session
{
    protected static $sessionStarted = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->startIfNotStarted();
    }

    function startIfNotStarted()
    {
        if (!static::$sessionStarted) {
            
            session_start();
            
            static::$sessionStarted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to worry about starting the session yourself as it will be started when you instantiate the class and it will only happen once.

This approach wouldn't be suitable if you had something like a `Person` class though as the data would be different each time and you wouldn't want to use the same data in difference instantiations.

```
class Person
{
    protected $firstname;

    protected $lastname;

    public function __construct($firstname, $lastname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }

    public function getFullname()
    {
        return "{$this->firstname} {$this->lastname}";
    }
}
```

```
$person1 = new Person('John', 'Smith');
$person2 = new Person('Jane', 'Foster');

$person1->fullname(); // John Smith
$person2->fullname(); // Jane Foster
```

If you were to use static methods / properties for this class then you could only ever have one person

```
class Person
{
    protected static $firstname;

    protected static $lastname;

    static function setName($firstname, $lastname)
    {
        static::$firstname = $firstname;
        static::$lastname = $lastname;
    }

    static function getFullname()
    {
        return static::$firstname . ' ' . static::$lastname;
    }
}
```

```
Person::setName('John', 'Smith');
Person::setName('Jane', 'Foster');
    
Person::getFullname(); //Jane Foster
```

---

**The debates**

You are probably going to see a lot of debates over which is better and what the best practices are when it comes to PHP (not just about static and not-static methods).

I wouldn't get bogged down with it though! If you find that one side makes more sense to you (and whatever you're building at the time) then go with that one. Standards and opinions change all the time in this community and half of the stuff that was a problem 5 years ago (or even less) will actually be non-issues today.

Take the `Laravel` framework as an example -- one of the (many) debates is that Facades are bad because they're static and make use of magic methods which is hard to test and debug. Facades are actually very easy to test and with the use of stack trace error reporting it isn't hard to debug at all. That's not to say their aren't caveats when it comes to testing static methods, but this is more to do with mocking/spying -- this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5961347/1033654) goes into it in a little more detail.

That being said, if you find the majority of people are saying the same thing and there isn't really a debate for the other side, there is probably a reason e.g. don't use `mysql_` functions or don't run queries inside a loops.

Comment: Ross, you are the Boss! I was very upset because my question was downvoted without providing any valid reason. But I am glad, you answered it and in such a great way. Thank you so much!!! :)

Comment: Another question, let say I make a class with `database_insert` method; which take some data and insert in DB. Does static method is suitable for that? And static class can hold only one value at the time. Right?

Comment: @Alena I would completely depend on your implementation. Personally, my approach to anything like this is to initially always reach for non-static methods and then make them static only if it's necessary / just makes sense to. If you're thinking about a database class then I would also look at `Singleton` http://phpenthusiast.com/blog/the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php. Also, maybe look in to SOLID principals as well, however please view SOLID as more of a it's good to do most of the time when you can rather than it's has to be done all of the time.